# Trigger custom implicit conversion on "copy"

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there anything horribly wrong with creating different representations of data behind the scenes when constructing a `std::vector<T>` from a `std::vector<U>`?

```
std::vector<Color> initialScene(Settings::HRes * Settings::VRes);

std::vector<Pixel> finalScene(std::begin(initialScene), std::end(initialScene));
```

With the `Pixel(const Color&)` constructor doing something along the lines of:

```
explicit Pixel(const Color& color) {
   // Basically swaps blue and red channels
   data[0] = color.blue;
   data[1] = color.green;
   data[2] = color.red;
}
```

Note: this is not exactly what the converting constructor does; it's more of an illustration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No problem with that at all, since it's not the `copy` which is doing the conversion (which would be strange) but the constructor.  Since the `vector` templates you've mentioned are clearly of different types, the operation you describe would not at all be unexpected.  It's little different from using `std::copy` to read from a file into an STL container, which is a common idiom.